# Recovery mode for tab A6 SM-T585

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset, boot-loop, hard-reset

my tablet entered a restarting loop I want to go to recovery mode but I can't using buttons I tried miracle box doesn't working how can I exit this loop or force it to get into recovery mode ?

Comment: let battery drain. keep holding home + volume up buttons, connect charger

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.